# Sampling traffic in python/scapy

Tags: python, scapy, sampling, network-monitoring

i'm currently looking to implement a basic traffic sampler using python and I'm wondering how to efficiently implement the sampler interval between each capture.
I am not using sFlow as I want to sample traffic on my NIC.

I have looked at scapy but it seems that it does not provide a sampling feature.
Therefore, in the processing function attached to sniff (e.g. sniff(prn=XXX) ) should I implement myself a timer to check if a packet should be specifically processed ?

Otherwise, I have an idea with the following code (basic example):

```
#Packet sniffer in python
#For Linux

import socket

#create an INET, raw socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)

# receive a packet
while True:
  sleep(1) # Timer ?
  print s.recvfrom(65565)
```

I've looked in the socket creation as well but didn't find any suitable answer.

My question is, what is the most efficient, performance-wise, way to capture and sample traffic on a network interface ?

Comment: You could use the `prn` parameter on the `sniff` function of scapy, then perform an action if (for instance), `time.time()` is greater than a stored value by 20sec

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, if you are going to have a delay/timer you need to `import time` or if you are using just `sleep(n)` to do `from time import sleep`. Secondly, it's my personal opinion that timers aren't really the best options for sniffing packets. Especially if you are filtering/looking for certain types of packets. Also to get any relevant details of a raw packet, you need to deconstruct it. The `struct` module in python is probably best for that and you need to know how to extract data from certain received packets. When receiving the packet data using `s.recvfrom(65535)`, this is stored in a tuple and you need to focus on the first element of this using something like:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
while True:
    try:
        packet = s.recvfrom(65565)
        packet = packet[0]
        #begin to analyse and deconstruct packet data
    except:
        pass
```

Each packet of data in constructed in a way the you can extract useful information from each one of them. A simple search on how they are packed can help you on knowing how to deconstruct them and show information. Look into the `struct` module and that should set you off! If you really need a delay for some reason, I would use a maximum of `sleep(0.5)`.

For efficiency, you may want to implement threading. If your code is working fine, this wouldn't necessarily be needed but if you wanted to, you could start a thread to deconstruct a received packet WHILE your NIC is still receiving packets. It would look SOMETHING like this:

```
import socket
import thread

def deconstructPacket(packet):
    #code to deconstruct packet

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
while True:
    try:
        packet = s.recvfrom(65565)
        packet = packet[0]
        thread.start_new_thread(deconstructPacket, packet)
    except:
        pass #or handle any errors
```

I hope this helped!!!